# My Nokia Lumia 610 - bad performance

Tags: 7.x, performance

My Nokia Lumia 610 performs very slow and poor. Even opening my applications takes very long before they start to run. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a factory reset (Using the Nokia Software Recovery tool). This will delete your files + apps though! You can back them up and restore them, but then you might have the same problem (slow phone)..

The 610 is really beginning to be an older model. You could consider upgrading to the 635 or 535; they're not very expensive and much faster.